# Cascade persist : One parent and multiple children(each having their own embeddedid )

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a parent entity called Player and two child entities called bat and ball.

PK of Player entity is 'playerId',
composite pk of ball is 'playerId(FK)' and 'ballColor', &
composite pk of bat is 'playerId(FK)' and 'batColor'

Note : player-to-bat is OneToOne and player-to-ball is OneToMany (unidirectional)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Ball> balls;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Bat bat;

// getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bat")
public class Bat implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -114046508592L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private BatEmbeddedId batEmbeddedId = new BatEmbeddedId();

    @MapsId("playerId")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bat_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Player player;

// getters and setters for player field
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ball")
public class Ball implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1108592L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private BallEmbeddedId ballEmbeddedId = new BallEmbeddedId();

    @MapsId("playerId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ball_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Player player;

// getters and setters for player field
}

@Embeddable
public class BatEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -91976886L;

@Column(name = "player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    
    @Column(name = "bat_color")
    private String batColor;
    
    public BatEmbeddedId() {}
    
    public BatEmbeddedId(Long playerId, String batColor) {
        super();
        this.playerId= playerId;
        this.batColor= batColor;
    }

// getters and setters for all fields
}


@Embeddable
public class BallEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -91976889990L;

@Column(name = "player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    
    @Column(name = "ball_color")
    private String ballColor;
    
    public BatEmbeddedId() {}
    
    public BatEmbeddedId(Long playerId, String ballColor) {
        super();
        this.playerId= playerId;
        this.ballColor= ballColor;
    }

// getters and setters for all fields
}


public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Player> {
    Player findByPlayerId(Long playerId);
}

@Service
public class myService{
     @Autowired
     PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    // Save logic for player
    Player player = new Player();


    BatEmbeddedId batEmId = new BatEmbeddedId();
//note i can't set the playerId here coz its not yet generated
    batEmId.setBatColor("white");

    Bat bat = new Bat();
    bat.setBatEmbeddedId(batEmId);
    bat.setPlayer(player);

    player.setBat(bat); // added bat to player object

    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

    BallEmbeddedId ballEmId1 = new BallEmbeddedId();
    BallEmbeddedId ballEmId2 = new BallEmbeddedId();
    ballEmId1.setBallColor("white");
    ballEmId2.setBallColor("red");

    Ball b1 = new Ball();
    Ball b2 = new Ball();
    b1.setBallEmbeddedId(ballEmId1);
    b2.setBallEmbeddedId(ballEmId2);

    balls.add(b1);
    balls.add(b2);

    //adding balls to player object
    player.setBalls(balls);

    //finally calling a save
    playerRepository.save(player); 
}
```

After running the above code am getting the following error :
`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

Am I doing something wrong in the save logic of these related entities ?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct your mapping like below:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bat")
public class Bat implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @EmbeddedId
    private BatEmbeddedId batEmbeddedId = new BatEmbeddedId();

    @MapsId("playerId")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Player player;

    // getters and setters for player field
}

@Embeddable
public class BatEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

    // ...

    // @Column annotation will be ignored as you use @MapsId("playerId") 
    // The column name will be taken from the @JoinColumn(name = "player_id") annotation
    // @Column(name = "player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    
    @Column(name = "bat_color")
    private String batColor;
    
    public BatEmbeddedId() {}
    
    public BatEmbeddedId(Long playerId, String batColor) {
        // super() is redundant 
        // super();
        this.playerId= playerId;
        this.batColor= batColor;
    }

    // getters and setters for all fields
    
    // The primary key class must define equals and hashCode methods,
    // consistent with equality for the underlying database types to which the primary key is mapped.
    // see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;

        BatEmbeddedId pk = (BatEmbeddedId) o;
        return Objects.equals( playerId, pk.playerId ) &&
               Objects.equals( batColor, pk.batColor );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash( playerId, batColor );
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ball")
public class Ball implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @EmbeddedId
    private BallEmbeddedId ballEmbeddedId = new BallEmbeddedId();

    @MapsId("playerId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Player player;

    // getters and setters for player field
}


@Embeddable
public class BallEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

    // ...

    // @Column(name = "player_id")
    private Long playerId;
    
    @Column(name = "ball_color")
    private String ballColor;
    
    public BatEmbeddedId() {}
    
    public BatEmbeddedId(Long playerId, String ballColor) {
        this.playerId= playerId;
        this.ballColor= ballColor;
    }

    // getters and setters for all fields
    // equals and hashCode 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the `insertable = false, updatable = false` from the player associations already? `@MapsId` should be able to handle without that. Also, you should mark the columns in the embeddable types as `nullable = false`.

If the problem still persists, are you sure that you are not doing anything else within the same transaction?

Are you using the latest Hibernate version 5.4.29? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.